# How would you translate "Weird, because now some are denying this" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción

> Weird, because now some are denying this

I'd say something like:

> Es raro/extraño porque ahora algunos estan negando?

What is a correct translation? Should I use *negando* or another? It sounds weird.  And what would be the correct translation of *"this"* in the sentence above? *esto*?

Answer (score 5):

I suppose that *this* refers to something that has been already introduced in the conversation, and is something known by the people speaking. So I would translate to something like this:

> Me extraña, porque ahora algunos lo están negando.

Note that *weird* is a personal opinion, so I tried to emphasise that in the translation. Other possible not-so-literal translations that respect the original meaning could be:

> Me extraña, porque ahora hay gente que lo niega.
>   Pues resulta que ahora algunos lo niegan.

Answer (score 2):

Literal version is:

> Extraño/raro, porque ahora algunos están negando esto.

However, *ahora* looks better in this position:

> Extraño/raro, porque algunos están negando esto ahora.

In some translations, you'll see a swap between the present continuous tense and the present simple tense:

> Extraño/raro, porque algunos niegan esto.

Anyhow, the three are perfectly idiomatic.